# Why does “toute façon” mean what it does?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Why does **'toute façon'** mean **'anyway'**?

The literal translation is *'all' (toute)* and *'fashion/way/method' (façon)*

I understand that in this context **toute** means **any**. But are there any other examples where *tout / toute / tous* can mean any? I always translate it as *all*.

Answer (score 4):

***De toute façon*** translates to **anyway** but that doesn't mean ***tout*** means **any**. It still does mean a generic, singular **all** here (all outcomes = whatever the outcome = any outcome = **every** outcome)

English simply can't word by word translate to *all ways* because this compound word is already taken for something different while French has *toujours* (*tous jours* / all days)

Other examples are:

> de toute espèce (whatever kind)
>
> de toute nature (ditto)
>
> ***Tout corps** plongé dans un liquide...* -> **Any object**, wholly or partially immersed in a stationary fluid, ... (Archimedes)

The singular form of "all" is "every" but English sometimes uses a generic *all* like for example in:

> Compare "All men are created equal" with *(tous) les hommes naissent et demeurent libres et égaux...*

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed common, where *tout* has the meaning of *chaque*, *n'importe quel(le)*, albeit maybe more in written French. Some examples:

> Tout condamné à mort aura la tête tranchée.
>
> Toute exception devra être approuvée par le directeur.
>
> Je me prépare à toute éventualité.
>
> Il sera traité comme tout autre citoyen.
>
> A tout seigneur, tout honneur (French proverb, it means that any important person is entitled to any honors that are due to them, especially when giving them some sort of priority).

Comment: Thank you for this list. However, I'm still reading the tout usage as all, in these sentences. 'Tout condamné à mort aura la tête tranchée' - I see as 'All condemned to death...' 'Je me prépare à toute éventualité' - 'I am prepared for all eventualities'. etc.

Comment: Yes, but "all" would then be used with a plural noun, not the singular as in French. This rather matches an equivalent wording in French, which is more frequent in spoken language. "Tous les condamnés à mort auront la tête tranchée", "Je me prépare à toutes les éventualités", "il sera traité comme tous les autres citoyens", "toutes les exceptions devront être approuvée par le directeur".

Comment: Or take it the other way round: *il sera traité comme tout autre citoyen* can be translated as *he will be treated like any other citizen*. *Toute exception devra être approuvée* can be *Any expection will require the approval of the director*. So in this sense, you could use "any" to translate "tout(e)".

Comment: aha! Now I get it. Thank you so much!